# Is it possible to filter Bluetooth Scan results to show devices with specific names

Tags: android

my app scans for Bluetooth devices, I only want it to show devices with a specific name (limiting the results viewed by the user).  Not entirely sure if this can be achieved? Please see screenshots below

Current Bluetooth scan result:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can filter it out.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
      // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
      // object and its info from the Intent.
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      String deviceName = device.getName();
      // 
      // use try-catch to keep tying on the logic -- John Melody added
      try {
        if (deviceName.contains("somethingsomething")) {
          System.out.println(String.format("Ok %s", deviceName));
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    //
    }
  }
};
```

Checkout[this][1] link

[1] : https: //developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#FindingDevices